# Use a vanilla JavaScript package in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aiming to use a Vanilla JavaScript package in a more sophisticated React app to build additional logic around the JavaScript package.

The JavaScript library is LabelStudio and docs can be found here: https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-frontend

However, when I try to import the LabelStudio I get an error saying `Module not found: Can't resolve 'label-studio'` , as described here https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-frontend/issues/55

Since my understanding of frontend code is limited, I am not sure whether this is something the developers did not expected users to do and just wanted them to use the entire library and customized instead of using the library as a component. My idea was to use the library as in the vanilla javascript example here:

```
<!-- Include Label Studio stylesheet -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/label-studio@0.7.1/build/static/css/main.0a1ce8ac.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the Label Studio container -->
<div id="label-studio"></div>

<!-- Include the Label Studio library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/label-studio@0.7.1/build/static/js/main.3ee35cc9.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Label Studio -->
<script>
  var labelStudio = new LabelStudio('label-studio', {
    config: `
      <View>
        <Image name="img" value="$image"></Image>
        <RectangleLabels name="tag" toName="img">
          <Label value="Hello"></Label>
          <Label value="World"></Label>  
        </RectangleLabels>
      </View>
    `,

    interfaces: [
      "panel",
      "update",
      "controls",
      "side-column",
      "completions:menu",
      "completions:add-new",
      "completions:delete",
      "predictions:menu",
    ],

    user: {
      pk: 1,
      firstName: "James",
      lastName: "Dean"
    },

    task: {
      completions: [],
      predictions: [],
      id: 1,
      data: {
        image: "https://htx-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/opensource/label-studio/examples/images/nick-owuor-astro-nic-visuals-wDifg5xc9Z4-unsplash.jpg"
      }
    },
    
    onLabelStudioLoad: function(LS) {
      var c = LS.completionStore.addCompletion({
        userGenerate: true
      });
      LS.completionStore.selectCompletion(c.id);
    }
  });
</script>
```

How can I make use of the above code in a React Component to facilitate dynamic data loading and use of state to customize the functions?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the library, I even copied their js output in their bundle and imported it in a React component and it crashes where the whole log is filled with `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`. But if I place that same js output in the public folder and run in a script tag inside index.html, it works.

Comment: Thank you for the experiment. Do you have any recommendation how to work around this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a solution making the npm module `label-studio` to work. I tried importing the [dist file](https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-frontend/tree/master/build/static/js) instead, but it errors

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

So here's a workaround until the maintainers address this.

Copy the JS file from [build/static/js](https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-frontend/tree/master/build/static/js), then place it in a script in the public folder on index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="%Your_Path_To_Label-Studio%/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The script file defines a global function variable, so you can access it in React by using the window object. The useEffect hook is to make sure the initialization is only run once.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const LabelStudio = window.LabelStudio; // label-studio script stores the api globally, similar to how jQuery does
  const myLabelStudioRef = useRef(null); // store it and then pass it other components

  useEffect(() => {
    myLabelStudioRef.current = new LabelStudio("label-studio", {
      config: `
      <View>
        <Image name="img" value="$image"></Image>
        <RectangleLabels name="tag" toName="img">
          <Label value="Hello"></Label>
          <Label value="World"></Label>  
        </RectangleLabels>
      </View>
    `,

      interfaces: [
        "panel",
        "update",
        "controls",
        "side-column",
        "completions:menu",
        "completions:add-new",
        "completions:delete",
        "predictions:menu",
      ],

      user: {
        pk: 1,
        firstName: "James",
        lastName: "Dean",
      },

      task: {
        completions: [],
        predictions: [],
        id: 1,
        data: {
          image:
            "https://htx-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/opensource/label-studio/examples/images/nick-owuor-astro-nic-visuals-wDifg5xc9Z4-unsplash.jpg",
        },
      },

      onLabelStudioLoad: function (LS) {
        var c = LS.completionStore.addCompletion({
          userGenerate: true,
        });
        LS.completionStore.selectCompletion(c.id);
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Use Label Studio container */}
      <div id="label-studio"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As far as storing the new instance of LabelStudio, there's many ways to go about it. You can store it as variable on the root component using either `useState` or `useRef` hooks and then pass it to child components. If you want to avoid manually passing variable down the component tree, then you need a state manager such as [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or Redux.

Comment: Thanks for the great work-around. I get the point of using the useEffect hook to initialize the component but if I need the config object continuously to first run the interface for task1, then for task2, task3, ... using task objects from the react state, where would you then place call to initiate `const labelstudio = ...`?

Comment: You can store it to the component state and pass it to other components that need it, or you can use state management, such as React Context or Redux, and store that instance in state store. I updated the question

Comment: Thanks for updating the response. This is very helpful but was not exactly what I meant - one last question around this. I will now initiate the instance of LabelStudio and store it in a variable. However, after the first task is done, I need to update the task to be a different task for the initiated LabelStudio object. How would you this if the LabelStudio object is already stored in the variable - would you initiate a new instance or is there a way to update the config object?

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic setup using LabelStudio as a module in a React component.

```
yarn add @heartexlabs/label-studio
```

```js
import LabelStudio from '@heartexlabs/label-studio'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

import '@heartexlabs/label-studio/build/static/css/main.css'

const ReactLabelStudio = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    new LabelStudio('label-studio', {
      config: {...},
      interfaces: [...],
      user: {...},
      task: {...},

      onLabelStudioLoad: function(LS) {
        const c = LS.annotationStore.addAnnotation({
          userGenerate: true,
        });
        LS.annotationStore.selectAnnotation(c.id);
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return <div id="label-studio" />
}

export default ReactLabelStudio
```