# How to know the correct nodejs package-name alternative to a vanilla javascript library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

#### TLDR

Given a downloaded vanilla javascript library file, how to locate the alternative in nodejs?
Some example mapping as below

| js library | nodejs package |
| --- | --- |
| sha256.js | crypto-js |
| elliptic.js | elliptic |
| Buffer.js | buffer |
| ... |  |

#### Detail

I'm forking a git repo here where several javascript libraries was downloaded and used in a nodejs web app.

E.g. `sha256.js` file [as imported here](https://github.com/anders94/public-private-key-demo/blob/master/views/layout.pug#L24C34-L24C40) in javascript, the corresponding one for nodejs is `crypto-js` package [as used here](https://gitlab.com/luutrinhthien/jdione-reactjs/-/blob/develop/src/service/crypto.js#L4) - this requires some tens of minute to figure it out

Some libraries will share same names for both; e.g. `elliptic` as used in js [here](https://github.com/anders94/public-private-key-demo/blob/master/views/layout.pug#L21) and sample used in nodejs [here](https://gitlab.com/luutrinhthien/jdione-reactjs/-/blob/develop/src/service/crypto.js#L1)

So what is the official way to map the package/library names between vanilla js and nodejs?

---

My [google search on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+know+the+correct+nodejs+package-name+alternative+to+a+vanilla+javascript+library%3F&oq=How+to+know+the+correct+nodejs+package-name+alternative+to+a+vanilla+javascript+library%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60.302j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) results not helpful.

The similar post I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62801255/248616) but that's more specific in label-studio package

---

What I've been doing is the google search for the need

i.e.

```
gg nodejs {package name} alternative to {library name} in javascript
```

Or copy the usage js code and google search it for nodejs

```
gg js CryptoJS.SHA256() alternative for nodejs
```

And of course, that takes maybe hour to figure out, and that will happen for every new package needed to map.

Comment: I think the best bet is do Google search only, I can't seem to find any website or application for this use case, If you find it please Tell us too!

Comment: It's not just an equivalence problem, either. By using open source packages, you are trusting them to some degree as well, so when choosing the right npm package you have to consider that as well. Research your npm package via socket.dev. (I've no connection with them, I found them via [Javascript Jabber episode 525](https://topenddevs.com/podcasts/javascript-jabber/episodes/supply-chain-security-part-2-jsj-525#))

Comment: @kushagra-aa yeah sure I'll share when found one

Comment: @JSmart523 so you mean npm packages ảe not trust-worthy?

Comment: It depends on your definition of trustworthy. Open source means volunteers, and nobody is perfect. On top of that, there have been some very famous hacks lately that were inserted by hackers taking ownership of open source projects and making a tiny change nobody noticed until after people were using it. Every tool, developer extension, and code dependency you use is a way your development supply chain can be hacked. Not saying don't do it, but be aware of the risks. Example: https://therecord.media/malware-found-in-npm-package-with-millions-of-weekly-downloads

Comment: what hacked package is it ^^

Comment: ua-parser-js was hacked only for a short amount of time, then fixed. My point is only that any code you write yourself might have security issues you don't expect, any code others write might have security holes *they* don't expect, and they (and you) might be hacked one day. What you do with this knowledge depends on you. If you're an international bank you likely already have infrastructure that indexes your applications, dependencies, and catches many security issues already. If you're small, maybe just never upgrading to the next version until it's been out for a while. 

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no universal solution for this. If the older version of the library includes a license comment at the top of the file, that definitely helps, but some probably won't. Some may be browser versions of Node builtins, making it even more confusing.

If there's config for Bower, JSPM, or some other script or config that deals with dependencies, that could help lead you in the right direction. Finding the earliest commit for a file might also sometimes give you some information. GitHub's code search is (sometimes) better than Google. But no universal solution, especially since many older libraries aren't maintained or published as npm packages.

Comment: Not all codes are from github...

Comment: May you share more why earliest commit helps?

Comment: No, but GitHub is a good place to start the search, because it's the most common code hosting platform. Earliest commit for a vendor library might be useful because the commit message, or the pull request/change request associated with it, may mention where the code came from.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow.

https://github.com/brix/crypto-js is a *JavaScript library of crypto standards.*

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-crypto/sha256-js is a part of
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-crypto-helpers

Each of them can be used where you need sha256  - one will perhaps be better suited to your need when you want to npm it, the other not.

I could not find a list of dependencies in the package.json in the project you mention